# Should I add Cache-Control: no-cache to GET endpoints of my REST API?

Tags: http, caching, browser-cache, offline-caching, http-caching

When creating REST API working with  POST/PUT is simple. They are non-idempotent and thus are NOT cached by browsers by default.

However when creating a GET endpoint, things get tricker. I have this fear that browsers(or a particular one) by default will try to cache GET requests whenever they can and I will end up with stale data.

#### Is this fear of aggressive caching real?

Let's take example of an endpoint `GET /articles/123/comments`.

Despite this endpoint being a GET endpoint, each request can return different content, as comments for the article get submitted.

- Will this this be cached?
- Will it be cached by particular aggressive browser?

Let's assume there are no headers related to cache served with the response.

```
content-length: 2518
content-type: application/json
date: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:51:59 GMT
status: 200
```

#### What is the best practice for avoiding stale data for GET requests?

There seem to be different strategies to solve this problem, but what would be the best way?

- cache-busting my GET calls via unique query string?

  eg. `GET /articles/123/comments?nonce=12312310980923409`
- adding `Cache-Control: no-cache` (will this always be respected?)
- adding `ETag: xyz_HASH_OF_MY_LIST_OF_COMMENTS`?
- adding `Cache-Control: max-age=0` (to disable caching)
- adding `Cache-Control: max-age=60` (to reduce max duration of caching)
- just don't worry and assume that without headers like `ETag, Last-Modified` the GET request won't be cached by any of the browsers?

Answer (score 3):

To a browser GET requests look the same, no matter if they originated by JavaScript to your REST API or by you entering an URL in the address bar.

### What happens if you don't set the caching headers?

The spec allows the browser to do whatever it wants.

By default, browsers cache responses to GET requests and use a "best guess" approach for the duration.

You should always set the caching explicitly to get consistent behavior.

For more details, see

- [No expires header sent, content cached, how long until browser makes conditional GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860216/no-expires-header-sent-content-cached-how-long-until-browser-makes-conditional/41897263#41897263)
- [How long does Google Chrome cache a resource if expires and/or no-cache headers are not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740822/how-long-does-google-chrome-cache-a-resource-if-expires-and-or-no-cache-headers)
- [How long are files usually kept in a browser's cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869800/how-long-are-files-usually-kept-in-a-browsers-cache)

### How to avoid stale content?

There is no simple answer to this. It depends how often your resource changes. If it never changes, you can cache it for a long time, for example a blog post. If it changes sometimes, you can cache it for a shorter time, for example a news API. If it changes "always", you shouldn't cache it, for example a social media news feed, stock price API, etc.